# MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS and Fixtures

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

When you generate a project using ember-cli you will have `MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS` turned on by default.

But for some reason it breaks fixture loading:

**adapters/application**

```
export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
```

**models/note**

```
var Note = DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
});

Note.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'text1'
  },
];

export default Note;
```

**routes/index**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('note');
  }
});
```

With `MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS` I get

> Error while loading route: Error: Assertion Failed: Unable to find
>   fixtures for model type notes@model:note:

And without everything works as expected.

Maybe I've missed something? Or is that just a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know what `MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS` does but I also discovered that my fixtures don't work if it is enabled. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997399/injecting-session-into-a-model) I found a solution where you don't have to disable it. You have to use `reopenClass` to define the fixtures so they get picked up correctly.

```
var Note = DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
});

Note.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'text1'
    }
  ]
});

export default Note;
```

Comment: I found this post explaining what setting MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS to true is used for. [Injecting a session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997399/injecting-session-into-a-model)